# install python package to a specific version of python?

Tags: python, numpy, installation

I have a remote machine with python 2.6 as the default package on the machine. I installed numpy using yum install numpy.

I then installed python 2.7 using the instructions available [python 2.7 install](http://tecadmin.net/install-python-2-7-on-centos-rhel/)  link in the directory /usr/src/. I then put this alias

```
alias python=/usr/src/Python-2.7.8/python
```

in ~/.bashrc.

So numpy is already installed on the machine but python 2.7 can't pick it up? Should I uninstall it? How do I install it for version 2.7.

The commands would be vary helpful.

Could I pip install to a specific version? I tried this command but it is incorrect.

```
pip-2.7 install numpy
```

Thanks

Comment: instead of chasing version and installations I would suggest you to use virtual environments. Refer here https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)

Comment: Also `python -m pip install numpy` is a neat trick if you want to use the right pip version for your `python` interpreter

Comment: *"I tried this command but it is incorrect"* - did you get an error message? On my Ubuntu machine the command would be `pip2.7` (without the hypen).

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
pythonx.y -m pip install numpy
```

to install numpy on python version x.y